# Format textfield while typing Ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Ive seen other examples and tried

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I just started coding my first Iphone App

This is what I am trying to do

I have 4 textfields and each has a limit on number of letters while typing I have done this using the below code

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
int valid;
    NSString *cs2 = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
//    int charCount = [cs2 length];

    if(textField == cvv){
        valid = 4;
    }else if(textField == cardName) {
        valid=26;
    }else if(textField == expDate) {
        valid=5;

//        if (charCount == 2 ) {
//            textField.text = [cs2 stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
//            textField.text = cs2; 
//            return YES;
//        }



    }else if(textField == acNumber) {
        valid=19;
    }


    return !([cs2 length] > valid);
```

Works fine till here, I have a textfield where the user enters Exp date and would like to format it as if I am entering 112 then it should display as 01/12 and if I enter 2 then it should display as 1122

I tried checking if the length of the textfield value is 2 then append a / but then that gives me when I enter 12 it gives 11/22

Comment: Just a suggestion:why don't you use iphone date picker for selecting date, it will provide date format and you do not have to handle it.

Comment: I agree date picker would have been easier for me too, but the requirements demand it to be typing with number pad and I have to format based on user input ....

Answer (score 0):

Like Nuzhat suggested, a datepicker is probably a good idea. Here's some code you can use for a popover datepicker. Basically, create a view controller that is a subclass of DateController (code below) and have it popover the textfield. Then, implement the delegate method in your view controller to update the textfield.

```
//DateController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol DateControllerDelegate
- (void) upDate:(NSDate*) date;
@end

@interface DateController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate>
- (IBAction)datePicker:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateWheel;
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) id<DateControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

//DateController.m
#import "DateController.h"

@implementation DateController
@synthesize dateWheel;
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)datePicker:(id)sender 
{
    [delegate upDate:dateWheel.date];
}

@end

//Add this to your ViewController.h
#import "DateController.h"

//This line should look like this
@interface ViewController:UIViewController <DateControllerDelegate>

//Add this to your ViewController.m
- (void) upDate:(NSDate*) date
{

    textField.text = [[date description] substringToIndex:10];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"dateSegue"])
    {
        DateController *foo = segue.destinationViewController;
        foo.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do is hook up the segue and name it dateSegue in storyboard.